# Column names after unnest() and unnest_longer()

Tags: r, tidyr

I am working with a tibble which has a nested list of data frames containing column names that repeat column names of the tibble.  I'm looking for the best way to unnest this tibble.  The tibble has a structure like this:

```
df <- tibble(
  g = c(1, 2, 3),
  x = c("a", "b", "c"),
  data = list(
    data.frame(x = 1, y = 2),
    data.frame(x = 4:5, y = 6:7),
    data.frame(x = 10, y = 99)
  )
)
```

Note that both `df$x` and `df$data[[1]]$x` exist.

I'm struggling to unnest and then rename or select columns by name.

`df %>% unnest(cols = "data")` fails due to the redundant names

`df %>% unnest_longer(col = "data")` works but

`` df %>% unnest_longer(col = "data") %>% select(`data$x`) `` fails: I can't select the column.  I have similar issues when trying to rename, etc.

I'm not even sure what to call the data structure that results from `df %>% unnest_longer(col = "data")`:

`df %>% unnest_longer(col = "data") %>% colnames()` shows the colnames to be g,x, and data, but

`df %>% unnest_longer(col = "data") %>% print()` prints what looks like a data frame with four columns, even though it is a 4 x 3 tibble.  What is this strange beast? And what's the right way to unnest?  I guess this might be using names_repair in unnest but I can't see how to do it.

Comment: Try `df %>% unnest(cols = "data", names_sep = "_")`. You'll get "data_x" and "data_y" as unnested columns. When you use `unnest_longer`, the result "data" column is still a list and have to be unnested.

Comment: thanks, my mistake was trying to use names_sep in unnest_longer